# Cannot lighten up 12V LED strip with Raspberry pi 3

Tags: pi-3, led, breadboard, mosfet

Bought a

> 12V 5M RGB LED Strip
>
> a 12V 5A power supply
>
> 6 IRLZ44N mosfets.

i am trying to light up the led strip with PiGPIO.
followed the https://dordnung.de/raspberrypi-ledstrip/ tutorial. and the led won't even light up.
i tried to connect the +V to the VCC of my LED Strip, and -V to the Red/Blue/Green input, it simply lights up. but cannot do it with raspberry pi

so, here is how i wired things:

mosfets:

- right pin -> ground of breadboard
- middle pin -> on of the LED RGB inputs
- left pin -> to GPIO pin 17 of the raspberry pi

power supply:

- -V -> ground of breadboard
- +V -> VCC of the LED Strip input

and also wired the raspberry pi GND to the ground of the breadboard

installed PiGPIO and ran these commands :

```
sudo pigpiod
pigs p 17 255
```

nothing works!

EDIT : here is the schematic for the mosfet :
http://www.irf.com/product-info/datasheets/data/irlz44n.pdf

Comment: Please give us more information about the LED strip that you have. The tutorial is for at least three different types of strips. The most important thing to know is the controller of each LED.

Comment: what is `right pin`, `middle pin` and `left pin` on mosfet? ... which is the gate, source and drain? .... can you provide a schematic?

Comment: @NomadMaker how do i get the chip model? I really don’t know

Comment: @jsotola http://www.irf.com/product-info/datasheets/data/irlz44n.pdf

Comment: If you bought this online, it should be on the packaging. If your led strip contains individually addressable leds, then it should be on the documentation or sale's page for the product. Apa102 is one of them, another is the WS2812B. They both are programmed with a serial protocol, but it's a different protocol dependent on the chip. The chip name might also be in the sample code for the product.

Comment: @NomadMaker i bought it from a store. There’s actually nothing on it. But two numbes on some black things : 151 and 331. https://ibb.co/f28f8z

Comment: It was just sold without packaging or any hint of what was on the strip? I was making the foolish assumption that this was a strip of programmable leds, but it's most likely just a non-programmable one. You should be able to light it up as if it were a large 12V RGB led.

Comment: Your question would be much easier to follow if you provided a schematic instead of a textual description of your wiring. See [How do I add a schematic to my question?](https://raspberrypi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2074/how-do-i-add-a-schematic-to-my-question)